# Can I use Cisco ASA's "NetFlow Security Event Logging" (NetFlow 9) for bandwidth monitoring

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, netflow

Cisco has introduced NetFlow 9 export in the latest software version for ASA firewalls. But it seems to be meant for event logging of security events only (as a replacement for syslog messages).

But can it still be used for bandwidth monitoring, too? And if so, how must the ASA be configured?

Here the [relevant info](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/asa/asa81/netflow/netflow.html) from the Cisco Website:

Answer (score 2):

Security Event Logging is something different to what you're after. I believe you want straight NetFlow (v5 will do) - exported to some type of analyzer.

I've used, and can recommend, ManageEngine Netflow Analyzer: http://www.manageengine.com/products/netflow/download-free.html

Grab the free edition, and fire this up on a server somewhere. Make sure the server's firewall permits traffic on port 9996 (UDP). Then, use the following config on your ASA to export network flow data:

```
flow-export destination outside_interface_name <netflow analyzer IP> 9996
flow-export template timeout-rate 1
flow-export delay flow-create 10

access-list netflow-export extended permit ip any any

class-map netflow-export-class
 match access-list netflow-export

policy-map global_policy
 class netflow-export-class
  flow-export event-type all destination <netflow analyzer IP>
```

Note that in my example, I have assumed you have a global_policy policy-map defined.

Browse to Netflow Analyzer and log in. Netflow analyzer will break down the ASA output into source/destination connections, including traffic in megabytes per connection, and will even perform port analysis to show you the applications in use.

This makes it particularly easy to see *when an employee is torrenting* for instance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the bandwidth monitoring provided by Cisco is limited in what it can do. I use and recommend Fire Plotter, which works with Cisco firewalls.

http://www.fireplotter.com/

Answer (score 0):

What detail of bandwidth monitoring do you need?

If all you need is basic per-interface usage then SNMP and something like Observium or Cacti is a much better solution.

If you need for example per client (on a shared inside network) then you need to use Netflow and a Netflow collector.